# Get data from stdclass Object - Count from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stdclass

I was looking for over 3 hours on the internet how to get data from stdclass Object and none of these solution I found worked.

So what I have is simple mysql query

```
$park = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM wp_richreviews WHERE review_status='1'");
```

And then print it

```
if($park)
{
   print_r($park); 
}
```

Then it will show this

```
stdClass Object ( [COUNT(1)] => 2 )
```

But I want to recieve just "2" and not the stdclass object bla bla..

can anyone help me please ? thank you!

Comment: Change `print_r` to `echo` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made life a little difficult for yourself by not giving the result column a nice easily accessible name

If you change your query so the column has a known name like this

```
$park = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(1) as count 
                        FROM wp_richreviews 
                        WHERE review_status='1'");
```

then you have a nice easily accessible property called `count`

```
echo $park->count;
```

Comment: Thank you this worked !:) Unfortunely it says I cannot accept your answer, but this worked ! thanks again

Comment: You have to wait 20 minutes I believe before you can accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to:

```
$park = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(1) as count 
                        FROM wp_richreviews WHERE review_status='1'");
```

and get **count value** with something like `$park['count']`;

Comment: do you know please how? :)